# How to check the variable using if condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

How to check the variable using if condition or esle is there any other way to get the below result

```
     SET @groupid=230;
         IF  (SELECT @groupid) > 0 THEN
        SET @conditionquery = CONCAT ("", " Groupid = ", (SELECT @groupid));
         END IF;
    SELECT @conditionquery
```

the output should be

```
Groupid=230
```

when i printing  @conditionquery

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (SELECT @groupid) > 0 THEN
```

Should just be

```
IF @groupid > 0 THEN
```

There are little more mistakes in your posted code. Change it like below

```
SET @groupid = 230;

IF @groupid > 0 THEN
    SET @conditionquery = "Groupid = " + @groupid;
END IF;

SELECT @conditionquery
```

Comment: i am getting an error message while using the above query Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF  groupid > 0 THEN
       SET conditionquery = CONCAT ("Groupid = ", groupi' at line 1

Comment: same error were displayed your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF  groupid > 0 THEN
       SET conditionquery = "Groupid = " + groupid' at line 1

Comment: @user2302158, post the little more code block. want to see what's there before `IF`

Comment: I just want to build dynamic string query , so if i get the groupid it should be added in condition. for eg: Select * from Table where groupid = 230 , if it comes as null or empty it should not be added which will be  eg: Select * from Table

Comment: @user2302158, your question isn't clear at all. edit your post and include more information.